# Фильтр массива объектов в javascript, если хотя бы одно свойство из объекта равно свойству из другого объекта массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, фильтрация

Прошу помощи в сабже. Пример массива:

```
arr = [
        {name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Ivanov'},
        {name: 'Anton', surname: 'Ivanov'},
        {name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Petrov'}
      ];
```

Отфильтровать по свойству name: 'Ivan' и вывести:

```
arr = [
        {name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Ivanov'},
        {name: 'Anton', surname: 'Ivanov'},
      ];
```

Прошу не готовое решение, а направить в нужное русло. Спасибо.

Comment: То есть, Вам необходимы уникальные значения? Поясните немного принцип Вашего фильтра.

Comment: Нет, не значения. Нужно найти объект со свойством name: 'Ivan', выкинуть все другие объекты, которые содержат это свойство и вернуть отфильтрованный массив. Аналогично и с {name: 'Anton', surname: 'Ivanov'}. Если встретится ещё один, два, ..., n объектов содержащих свойство name: 'Anton'- их тоже выкинуть.

Comment: `arr.filter((item, i, arr) => arr.findIndex(it => it.name === item.name) == i)`

Comment: Благодарю за короткий вариант!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
arr = [
  {name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Ivanov'},
  {name: 'Anton', surname: 'Ivanov'},
  {name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Petrov'}
];

function filterByProp(arr, prop) {
  var seen = {};
  var result = arr.filter(item => {
    if (seen[item[prop]]) {
      return false;
    } else {
      seen[item[prop]] = true;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(filterByProp(arr, "name"));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за готовый код. В таком случае не могли бы пояснить примерно его механизм? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @KonstantinVeselovskii Метод массива `filter`, скобочное обращение  к свойствам объекта, значения свойства с именем `prop`, которые уже попадались - в объекте `seen`.

Comment: Про скобки и filter предельно понятно в принципе. Я не совсем въехал в логику, а именно для чего вводится пустой объект seen.

Comment: @KonstantinVeselovskii В этот объект собираются уникальные значения свойства, по которому фильтруется массив.

Comment: Благодарю любезно!